# Как выполнить внешнюю программу под другим пользователем в php?

Tags: php, cmd, exec

В скрипте вызов внешней программы происходит следующим образом:

```
exec("cls_symstore_V6.cmd"); // вызов командника
```

Мне нужно, чтобы cmd-файл выполнялся под другим пользователем.

Как это можно реализовать посредством php?

Answer (score 2):

запустить скрипт от этого пользователя например по средством крона или терминала. Ну или же создать пользователя без пароля и авторизовываться под ним перед выполнением команды. Но мало вероятно что это прокатит. Лучше задать группу для программы cls_symstore_V6.cmd www-data либо права для выполнения гостем для программы.